# aws sdk assumeRole not taking effect

Tags: java, aws-sdk, assume-role

ive got the below segment of code running. My calls to aws work fine but now that ive had to switch roles its running into problems making it take effect as it seems im still stuck in the original role.

```
    public void awsAssumeRoleUsingEnvironmentVariable(Regions region, String roleARN, String roleSessionName) throws Exception {
        AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider())
                .withRegion(region)
                .build();

        GetCallerIdentityRequest request = new GetCallerIdentityRequest();
        GetCallerIdentityResult response = stsClient.getCallerIdentity(request);

        System.out.println("CURRENT ROLE ASSUMED IS: " + response.toString());

        request = new GetCallerIdentityRequest();

        System.out.println("EXECUTING ASSUME ROLE");
        AssumeRoleRequest roleRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest()
                .withRoleArn(roleARN)
                .withRoleSessionName(roleSessionName);

        AssumeRoleResult roleResponse = stsClient.assumeRole(roleRequest);

        Credentials sessionCredentials = roleResponse.getCredentials();

        response = stsClient.getCallerIdentity(request);

        System.out.println("CURRENT ROLE ASSUMED IS: " + response.toString());
    }
```

The getCallerIdentity is returning the same role each time

Edit: 
Just trying to work it out its definitely an issue with the way I've coded this up by trying to use the credentials returned using the AWSCLI. When I do a `System.out.println()` on the `sessionCredentials` variable produced when i run my app, and then manually export the returned keys using the below...

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=RoleAccessKeyID
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=RoleSecretKey
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=RoleSessionToken
```

Followed by a..

`aws sts get-caller-identity`

The correct role is returned, so my java code assumeRole seems to be working and getting credentials but its like Im not setting the client correctly so its not using the role its just assumed.

Many thanks

Comment: Have you seen this? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AuthUsingTempSessionTokenJava.html

Comment: @drum thankyou, this helped alot. I wasnt using the `sessionCredentials` object, setting the `BasicSessionCredentials` object and passing that to my AmazonEC2 object worked perfectly.

Comment: Hi , Even i am also facing the same issue, can you pls share the latest code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, use `sessionCredentials` to create a new `BasicSessionCredentials` which can be passed to any Resource client.

Sample code here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AuthUsingTempSessionTokenJava.html

```
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.SdkClientException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicSessionCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectListing;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenService;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AssumeRoleRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AssumeRoleResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.Credentials;

public class MakingRequestsWithIAMTempCredentials {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String clientRegion = "*** Client region ***";
        String roleARN = "*** ARN for role to be assumed ***";
        String roleSessionName = "*** Role session name ***";
        String bucketName = "*** Bucket name ***";

        try {
            // Creating the STS client is part of your trusted code. It has
            // the security credentials you use to obtain temporary security credentials.
            AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                                                    .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                                                    .withRegion(clientRegion)
                                                    .build();

            // Obtain credentials for the IAM role. Note that you cannot assume the role of an AWS root account;
            // Amazon S3 will deny access. You must use credentials for an IAM user or an IAM role.
            AssumeRoleRequest roleRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest()
                                                    .withRoleArn(roleARN)
                                                    .withRoleSessionName(roleSessionName);
            AssumeRoleResult roleResponse = stsClient.assumeRole(roleRequest);
            Credentials sessionCredentials = roleResponse.getCredentials();

            // Create a BasicSessionCredentials object that contains the credentials you just retrieved.
            BasicSessionCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(
                    sessionCredentials.getAccessKeyId(),
                    sessionCredentials.getSecretAccessKey(),
                    sessionCredentials.getSessionToken());

            // Provide temporary security credentials so that the Amazon S3 client 
        // can send authenticated requests to Amazon S3. You create the client 
        // using the sessionCredentials object.
            AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                                    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
                                    .withRegion(clientRegion)
                                    .build();

            // Verify that assuming the role worked and the permissions are set correctly
            // by getting a set of object keys from the bucket.
            ObjectListing objects = s3Client.listObjects(bucketName);
            System.out.println("No. of Objects: " + objects.getObjectSummaries().size());
        }
        catch(AmazonServiceException e) {
            // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process 
            // it, so it returned an error response.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(SdkClientException e) {
            // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the client
            // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```